# CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load: https://dev-eccc.env.xxxx.com/ via Gitlab CI job

Tags: gitlab-ci, cypress

I have setup a Gitlab ci/cd job to execute all cypress integration tests. I found that all tests are getting fail due to home URL is getting failed to load by cy.visit().
On my local machine it is working fine.
below is the complete Error trace:

```
 CypressError: `cy.visit()` failed trying to load:
        https://dev-eccc.env.ihsmarkit.com/
        We attempted to make an http request to this URL but the request failed without a response.
 We received this error at the network level:
> Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dev-eccc.env.ihsmarkit.com
Common situations why this would fail:
- you don't have internet access
- you forgot to run / boot your web server
- your web server isn't accessible
- you have weird network configuration settings on your computer
  Because this error occurred during a `before all` hook we are skipping the remaining tests in the current suite: `Facility Register`
   at http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156433:23
   at visitFailedByErr (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:155794:12)
   at http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:156432:11
   at tryCatcher (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:10130:23)
   at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8065:31)
   at Promise._settlePromise (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8122:18)
   at Promise._settlePromise0 (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8167:10)
   at Promise._settlePromises (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:8243:18)
   at _drainQueueStep (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4837:12)
   at _drainQueue (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4830:9)
   at Async.../../node_modules/bluebird/js/release/async.js.Async._drainQueues 
   (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4846:5)
   at Async.drainQueues (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/runner/cypress_runner.js:4716:14)
   From Your Spec Code:
   at Object.homepage_test (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/eccc- 
   app-ui-cypress/API/register_api.ts:71:8)
   at Context.eval (http://localhost:45271/__cypress/tests?p=cypress/integration/eccc-app-ui- 
   cypress/API/register_api.ts:13:25)

    From Node.js Internals:
    Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND dev-eccc.env.ihsmarkit.com
     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:60:26)
```

Comment: Have you checked all the cases listed by the error (no internet, web server up and running, etc.?

Comment: All Tests are working fine. I just found that this URL actually getting failed to load by calling cy.visit('xxx') in gitlab ci/cd job. But the same URL is working fine with my local machine  cypress run.

Comment: I also tried with other URL like cy.visit("https://example.cypress.io/commands/viewport"); in same CI/CD job and this is also working fine.

Comment: Does the dev server have any whitelist or any other setting that would block request from CI?

Comment: not like this. I also tried it with git bash and also able to access it. I mean cy.visit() works fine with git bash as well but it is failing on gitlab ci.

Comment: Any solution to this? I am facing the same error